# Engine hiccups/stutters when accelerating under load

Tags: transmission, hyundai, acceleration, elantra

My 2007 Elantra 5-speed hiccups when I shift a *little* too early (i.e., 18 mph instead of 20 mph) into 3rd gear (similar behavior in other gears sometimes).  This is especially pronounced when rounding a corner or driving uphill from a stop sign.  If I step on the gas too hard, I get a similar behavior until I reach a higher speed.  I wonder if this has something to do with fuel delivery or ignition (or both?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing my fuel pump assembly (because it was also mis-reporting the fuel level.  The shuddering continued, so I've eliminated the fuel pump/delivery as an issue.

I bought a new coil pack and spark plug wires -- I figured I would just replace the spark plug wires first, since it takes less work.  Voila!  The shuddering went away.  I also feel a bit more torque from the motor as well.  Glad that simple fix solved the problem -- now to get a refund on the new coil pack...